# Compare running totals of different years

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

I'm trying to graph running totals by year week and slicing it by year. My columns are:

```
[date], [week#], [month#], [year], [usermame], [transaction]
```

[Data Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/va942.jpg)

I'm currently using this formula:

```
=CALCULATE(SUM(data[transaction]),FILTER(ALL(data),data[date]<=MAX(data[date]))
```

[Transaction Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzhPU.jpg)

but the when I graph it on my pivot (x-axis: week#,y-axis:transaction), it takes into account all the data from 2010. I only need to graph the year 2015 and 2016. Also, the graph starts where the running count left off from the previous year. I hope to start each year's count to 0.

I tried this formula:

```
=CALCULATE(SUM(data[transaction]),FILTER(ALL(data),data[date]<=MAX(data[date]),YEAR(data[date])=2016)
```

It starts the count at 0 but then I wouldn't be able to graph 2015 and compare it against 2016 data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
=CALCULATE(SUM(data[transaction]),[year]=2015||[year]=2016)
```

Also, if you are trying to do year over year, you will need to derive an adjusted year column to use as the row or X-Axis. then use [Year] as your series. I typically create my adjusted year in SQL.

My Logic:

**2016** data - as is

**2015** data - add 364 days to the day field

*i.e. where [day] between 01/01/2015 and 12/31/2015 then add 364 days to [Day] etc..*

**2014** Data - add 728 days

Other years you will need to do the same incremental. This ignores leap years as you are aligning to a day of the week which is a constant 7 days per week and never fluctuates. Once you have created this **AdjustedYear** field/column you can now use this for YoY analysis.The above date add will give you the day and then you can derive the year based off of that. Also to note, with this approach you will have 1-2 days stay within the same year as January 1st plus 364 is December 31st. I filter this off depending what graphs i create.

I hope this helps and I didn't leave anything off.

Answer (score 0):

So one column with weekly running totals that resets for every year?

I think using SUMX and the EARLIER function might help.

I think this formula might be what you are looking for:

=SUMX(FILTER(Table,AND([week#]<=EARLIER([week#]),[year]=earlier([year]))),[transaction])

Comment: Hi. I'm getting this error:

`EARLIER/EARLIEST refers to an earlier row context which doesn't exist.`

Comment: Sorry, make sure you use the table reference also. So 'Table'[week#] and 'Table'[year]

Comment: Hi, not sure what I'm doing wrong but it still give me the same error.

Comment: Strange, maybe edit your question and paste a small bit of data into it and i'll have a look.

Comment: Attached a clip of how my current graph looks like.

Comment: Ok will try replicate. Just to make sure, you are trying: =SUMX(FILTER('Table_name',AND('Table_name'[Week]<=EARLIER('Table_name'[Week]),'Table_name'[Year]=earlier('Table_name'[Year]))),[Transactions])

Comment: Yup. Power Pivot is giving me an error highlight this specific part of the formula:

=SUMX(FILTER('Table_name',AND('Table_name'[Week]<=`EARLIER('Table_name'[Week])`,'T‌​able_name'[Year]=earlier('Table_name'[Year]))),[Transactions])